# .Net Core Businnes Layer Best practice

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a lot of Entities User, Socialmedia, Image, Video, DriverLicense Etc...
I want to know best practice, I have business layer, Checking all my user related tables in one service? Or write separate services for each.  Example;

ISocailMediaService
IImageService
IVideoService
Etc..

I want to know best practice... Because I have 43 entities.
how to do
thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good practice to separate them following entities. But you have alot of entities, then it's best practice to follow your controller. For example, you have SocialController, then use ISocialService. You can use many necessary repositories like SocialMediaRepository + ImageRepository + VideoRepository in ISocialService.cs/SocialService.cs.